# creating indexeddb using fetch while activating serviceworker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, indexeddb

I am trying to create an indexeddb by fetching data from a server and putting it in a store following this example (the [idb library](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) is used here).

```
function createDB() {
idb.open('products',    1,  function(upgradeDB) {
        var store   =   upgradeDB.createObjectStore('beverages', {keyPath: 'id'});
        store.put({id:  123,    name:   'cheese',   price:  10.99,  quantity:   200});
        store.put({id:  321,    name:   'meat', price:  8.99,   quantity:   100});
        store.put({id:  222,    name:   'sugar',    price:  11.99,  quantity:   300});
 });
}
```

using the above example everything works fine and I see the data stored in Indexeddb , but when I modified the example above to the following I don't find the data stored similarly.

```
function createDB() {
idb.open('restaurants-reviews', 1, function(upgradeDB) {
    let store = upgradeDB.createObjectStore('restaurants', { keyPath: 'id'});

    fetch(`http://localhost:1337/restaurants`).then(response => response.json())
    //.then(responses => {
    //    return Promise.all(responses.map(response => store.put(response)))
   .then(responses => responses.map(response => store.put(response)))
    });
}
```

later in the serviceworker file the following code is used in both cases to create the data while activating the serviceworker.

```
 self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
 e.waitUntil(
    createDB()
  );
 });
```

Why things are ok in the first example while not working in the second one ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `Promise.all` for? It's not being used anywhere.

Comment: @CertainPerformance , thanks for your comment , I have commented the Promise.all in the code above and used map (without Promise.all) , and still not able to find any data stored, do you see another mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you are not calling an asynchronous function, so it will work every time. In the second example you are calling an asynchronous function, fetch, so it will always fail. You cannot use asynchronous functions within indexedDB event handlers. Event handler code generally must be synchronous.

To fix this, change how you arrange the async code. In other words, instead of doing connect-fetch-store, you will want to refactor to fetch-connect-store. This way the on-open handler that does the storing has no async call within its function body.

Just to be really clear, there are other ways to do this, I am simply advising you of a way that avoids all problems. If you want a hackish way (something I would not suggest) that still kind of looks like your current code, then it simple. Do not try and reuse the `store` variable in the fetch handler. `store` is an instance of IDBObjectStore. An instance of a store is a living thing, tied to the transaction where it was created. Your transaction is tied to the db. The transaction itself will timeout if it finds no requests. Because you have a call to fetch in between creating the transaction and creating put requests using the transaction, the transaction times out because no requests were scheduled within the right window of time (the same tick of the event loop). Therefore, a hacky way would be to instead create the transaction, then the store, and then the put requests, all within the fetch hander. The db connection will still be open at that point since it is a page-lifetime variable that is generally valid until closed. Again this is not well-written code, or an approach I would consider very good, but it is possible. Furthermore you are doing this all in the upgrade handler, which is also just bad, but anyway note that you need to access the implicit transaction for that instead of creating one.

Something like:

```
//...
fetch(...).then(_ => {
  // this might be wrong, you have to walk back to the transaction,
  // it might be something like upgradeDB.source.transaction, I don't 
  // know, this is an obvious example of why you should be careful
  // when using wrapper libraries, because here you need the
  //IDBOpenRequest, not the IDBDatabase, but you don't have it
  var txn = upgradeDB.transaction;
  var store = txn.objectStore('restaurants');
  responses.map(response => store.put(response));
});
```

Comment: As a followup, note that what is happening in your code is that your call to `store.put` throws an exception, but this exception is trapped by the promise, and you are not checking for promise-trapped exceptions (rejections), so you are hiding the error.